# React error during button click and adding data to database

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, mdbootstrap

I'm trying to add data into a database and display it in a table on my front-end at the same time. Adding the data into the database is done by a button click.

The data is added to the database without any problems but when trying to display it in the table I just get some errors.[The error picture is here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hJgMX.jpg)

The table I'm using looks like this (react bootsrap datatable)

```
<MDBDataTable
            striped
            small
            data={data}
            tbodyTextWhite
            theadTextWhite
            noBottomColumns
          />
```

The **data** variable which is an array looks like this:

```
const data = {
    columns: [
      //RANDOM COLUMNS HERE
    ],
    rows: tableRowsData(history_numbers_user_database),
  };
```

Example of output for rows:

```
    {
      id: "4",
      nr: "50898980",
      service: "ps5",
      id3: "500",
      delete: "yes",
    },
    {
      id: "5",
      nr: "50898980",
      service: "tv",
      id3: "500",
      delete: "yes",
    }
```

The **tableRowsData(history_numbers_user_database)** looks like this

```
const tableRowsData = (database_data) => {
    if (!database_data) {
      return [];
    }

    return database_data;
  };
```

and the **history_numbers_user_database** looks like this:

```
  const history_numbers_user_database = useSelector((state) => {
    console.log(state);
    return state.auth.user ? state.auth.user.history_phone_numbers : "";
  });
```

On the button click data needs to be added to the **history_numbers_user_database** (a new row needs to be added to the table as well) in the database and it should be displayed dynamically in the front-end.

The **data** variable should always be an array and I'm guessing that's why I'm facing this issue but I don't understand how the button click which change the variable type or if it's something related to re-rendering.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
const tableRowsData = (database_data) => {
    if (!database_data) {
      return [];
    }

    return database_data;
  };
```

You are calling this function with a string, and in it's second case it just returns what you passed into it.
In your `history_numbers_user_database` selector, it returns an empty string at the end of the ternary.
So when you call `tableRowsData("")`, it returns a string, which is not an array, hence `.filter is not a function`.

Comment: I tried a changing the history_numbers_user_database selector to return an empty array at the end of the ternary. Still not working. Any idea what the fix would look like?

Comment: @Ali It's hard to say without seeing the entire code. Make sure that `history_phone_numbers` is an array too. Add a log for the output of `tableRowsData`, and work backwards to locate the point of failure.

Comment: Found the issue. Thanks!